# PHP Removing Duplicates Spaces

Tags: php, preg-replace, trim

Why does this not work?

```
$content=file_get_contents('whatever.txt');
$content=str_replace("\r\n","\n",$content); // Convert linebreaks
$content=str_replace("\n",' ',$content); // Remove linebreaks
$content=preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$content); // Remove all duplicate spaces
$content=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\s]/','',$content); // Remove all non-letters
$content=trim($content);
$content=explode(' ',$content);
```

Some of the values are still empty spaces:

E.g.

```
$content[123] = '';
```

Do I understand something incorrectly? Surely there should be none?

Comment: Well for a start, the first two `str_replace`s are unnecessary - the first `preg_replace` would do the same job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that whole thing could be summed up/fixed in these lines:

```
$content = file_get_contents('whatever.txt'); // Get file
$content = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\s]/', '', $content); // Strip non-alpha/whitespace
$content = preg_split('/\s+/', $content, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // Split by whitespace and remove empty elements
```

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but it does not do the same. - Ah now you found it :)

Comment: @hakre Just realised and added the `preg_replace` to strip non-alphas, and spread out across multiple lines for readability.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you specifically, but you could just try this instead:

```
$content = file_get_contents('whatever.txt');
$content = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\s]+/', '', $content); // Remove all non-letters
$content = trim($content); // Trim
$content = preg_split('/\s+/', $content); // Split
```

This leaves out redundant things and the [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) is taking care of one or multiple white-space characters at once (this includes `\r` and `\n`).

**Edit:** Just added the trim to prevent empty tokens at the beginning and end (if applicable). This would be done as well by using `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag, however, that would do it in muliple places (in theory), so to hide what might have been the error in OP.

Answer (score 1):

try to print your final content and see how many extra white spaces being printed which causing an empty element in array after using explode

Comment: Oh there are about 250 white spaces per 5000 words.